# Parse html according to jquery with Php DOMDocument

Tags: php, jquery

With jQuery i can fetch the required content from html.

```
var description =  $(".singlePostDescription .description > p:eq(0)").text();
var download_link = $(".row.video-bg .post-title p span:eq(2) a").attr("href");
```

I'm attempting to do the same thing with PHP DOMDocument.

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($returned_content);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$description = $xpath->query('//div[@class="singlePostDescription"]/div[@class="description"]/p[1]');
$download_link = $xpath->query('//div[@class="video-bg"]/div[@class="description"]/p/span[3]/a');
```

How do i get the `text()` for `description` and `href` for `download_link`?